# How to use yield_context as the handler of resolver.async_resolve?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-asio

Using [`yield_context`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/yield_context.html) as the handler of Asio async operations in stackful coroutine is awesome! But [`ip::basic_resolver::async_resolve`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__basic_resolver/async_resolve/overload1.html)'s handler has a different signature than simply receiving an error code (I'm curious about the reason why doesn't it instead take a `resolver::iterator &` as a parameter in `async_resolve`, like the `basic_socket<Protocol1, SocketService> &` paramenter in [`basic_socket_acceptor::async_accept`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_socket_acceptor/async_accept/overload1.html)). Is there a way to use `yield` as the handler of it?

The same question also applies to [`async_connect`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_connect.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As documented in the [Stackful Coroutines overview](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/spawn.html), when passing a [`yield_context`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/yield_context.html) as the handler to an [initiating function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/asynchronous_operations.html) whose asynchronous operation's handler has the form:

```cpp
void handler(boost::system::error_code ec, result_type result);
```

the initiating function will return `result_type`.  In this case, [`basic_resolver::async_resolve()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__basic_resolver/async_resolve/overload1.html)'s handler type requirement is [ResolverHandler](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ResolveHandler.html), which has the form:

```cpp
void resolve_handler(
    const boost::system::error_code& ec,
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator iterator)
```

Thus, `basic_resolver::async_resolve(..., yield_context)` will return `resolver::iterator`.

---

Here is a complete minimal example demonstrating this behavior:

```cpp
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/spawn.hpp>

int main()
{
  boost::asio::io_service io_service;

  boost::asio::spawn(io_service,
    [&](boost::asio::yield_context yield)
    {
      using tcp = boost::asio::ip::tcp;
      tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);

      // The async_resolve initiating function will return an iterator, as
      // a yield_context is being passed as a handler.
      tcp::resolver::iterator iterator = resolver.async_resolve(
          tcp::resolver::query("www.google.com", "80"), yield);

      // Iterator over endpoints.
      for(tcp::resolver::iterator end; iterator != end; ++iterator)
      {
        std::cout << iterator->endpoint().address().to_string() << std::endl;
      }
    });

  io_service.run();
}
```

Output:

```
74.125.227.209
74.125.227.210
74.125.227.211
74.125.227.212
74.125.227.208
2607:f8b0:4000:80a::1012
```

Comment: Note that you can also write `std::cout << iterator->endpoint()<< std::endl;`